# Paradox between actual runtime and runtime complexity

Tags: c++, hashmap

Solution with Complexity O(N*M), where N is the number of strings and M is the max length of string in the input vector. Runtime for 101 test cases :92 ms.

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<string>> groupAnagrams(vector<string>& strs) {
        ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
        cin.tie(0);
        map <vector<int>, vector<int>> mp;
        for(int i=0;i<strs.size();i++){
            vector <int> dum(26);
            for(int j=0;j<strs[i].length();j++){
                dum[strs[i][j]-97]++;
            }
            mp[dum].push_back(i);
        }
        vector <vector<string>> out;
        for(auto i=mp.begin();i!=mp.end();i++){
            vector <string> dumS;
            for(auto j=i->second.begin();j!=i->second.end();j++){
                dumS.push_back(strs[*j]);
            }
            out.push_back(dumS);
        }
        return out;
    }
};
```

Solution with Complexity O(N*M*logM), where N is the number of strings and M is the max length of string in the input vector. Runtime for 101 test cases :80 ms.

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<string>> groupAnagrams(vector<string>& strs) {
        ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
        cin.tie(0);
        vector <string> strsCopy(strs.size());
        strsCopy = strs;
        vector <vector<string>> out;
        map <string,vector<int>> mp;
        for(int i=0;i<strs.size();i++){
            sort(strs[i].begin(),strs[i].end());
            mp[strs[i]].push_back(i);
        }
        for(auto i=mp.begin();i!=mp.end();i++){
            vector <string> dum;
            for(auto j=i->second.begin();j!=i->second.end();j++){
                dum.push_back(strsCopy[*j]);
            }
            out.push_back(dum);
        }
        return out;

    }
};
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: If you want to do benchmarking and measurements, first of all build with optimization enabled. Secondly you generally need large data-sets, in the range thousands to maybe even millions.

Comment: My question is if the runtime complexity is O(NM) then shouldn't it run faster than the code with complexity O(NMlogM)?

Comment: No.  Complexity ("Big O notation") does not describe the _speed_ of an algorithm.  It describes how the algorithm **scales**.

Comment: If you want to compare complexity, I would disable all optimizations. I don't know where the compiler would optimize and if it would have different effects in each algorithm. second, the big O notation hides some information, it make sense for VERY large datasets. for example, you may have a 100000+N alg. and a N*N alg., the second one is worse for huge datasets but better for smal datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contrasting terms used, namely *Runtime* and *Time complexity*, are not the same.

The former is a measure of the time taken by your program to run in terms of time-precision units (nanoseconds, microseconds and so forth), the corresponding functions for which can be availed by using libraries such as `ctime` and `chrono` in `c++`.

The later pertains to the *trend* in runtimes following the size of input to your program. It follows asymptotic complexity bounds wherein for varying size of input you will see the difference in runtime eventually scaling.

For small input sizes, most algorithms won't make a notice-able difference but large enough inputs (often incorporated in test cases) will suffice to test that.